# header file isn't found by cmake

Tags: c++, build, cmake

I have a folder with only headers.

In my **config** project I need some interfaces of the **param** project

```
src
  CMakeList.txt
  - config
    - CMakeList.txt
  - param
    - CMakeList.txt
    - parameter.h
```

This is inside my **config** CMakeList.txt

```
project(config)
file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES "${config_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")

add_library(config ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(config PUBLIC "${param_SOURCE_DIR}")
target_include_directories(config PUBLIC "${Utils_SOURCE_DIR}/include")

qt5_use_modules(config Core)
target_link_libraries(config)
```

My **param** library CMakeList.txt is (it needs Utils too)

```
project(param)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADERS "${param_SOURCE_DIR}/*.h")

add_library(param INTERFACE)
```

Then in my config project I have a class that include one of the interface and when building it doesn't find it. "parameter.h" file not found.

```
/usr/local/bin/clang++   -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_NO_DEBUG -I/builds/modules/project/src/config -I~/modules/project/src/config -I/usr/include/eigen3 -I~/modules/libs/utils/include -isystem ~/devel/qt5/qtbase/include -isystem ~/devel/qt5/qtbase/include/QtCore -isystem ~/devel/qt5/qtbase/./mkspecs/linux-g++  -fPIC -std=gnu++11 -o CMakeFiles/config.dir/configuration.cpp.o -c ~/modules/project/src/config/configuration.cpp
```

One of the source file in config cannot compile because of :

```
fatal error: 'parameter.h' file not found
#include "parameter.h"
```

Comment: Use `make VERBOSE=on` to see whether the includes where added. Your error message is kind of short.

Comment: It does not get included. It's not in the list of folder listed. I see the Utils folder.

Comment: Can you double check (using `message`) that your variables param_SOURCE_DIR and Utils_SOURCE_DIR are the ones you expect?

Comment: @usr1234567 yes the directories are the one expected.

Answer (score 0):

In `src/CMakeLists.txt` you obviously need

```
include_directories(param)
```

line. Alternatively, you can use `include_directories(../param)` in `src/config/CMakeLists.txt`.

The `include_directories()` command adds specified directories to compiler search paths for all targets declared below it in current `CMakeLists.txt` and every `add_subdirectory`ed one.